# Iterating over a string with string::size_type vs int

Tags: c++, string, iteration

This is the piece of code I'm working with on TDM-GCC with C++14 standard (32-bit/Windows 10):

```cpp
class var
{
private:
    vector<int> num;
public: 
    var(string x)
    {
        for(int i = x.size()-1; i >= 0; i--) // Notice use of INT
            num.push_back(x[i]-'0');
    }
};

int main()
{
    var num1("232");
    return 0;
}
```

Works perfectly fine, but best-practices (and several SO answers) say that I should be using `string::size_type` instead of `int` because the strings might be longer than what `int` can hold.

Now, when I replace `int` with `string::size_type`, something strange happens; the following code compiles but when I execute it, it does nothing. Instead windows pops-up with the **"thisProgram.exe has stopped working..."** dialog and the terminal closes abruptly. *(with an arbitrarily large return code)*

```cpp
class var
{
private:
    vector<int> num;
public: 
    var(string x)
    {
        // Everything is same except the following line has string::size_type instead of int
        for(string::size_type i = x.size()-1; i >= 0; i--) 
            num.push_back(x[i]-'0');
    }
};

int main()
{
    var num1("232");
    return 0;
}
```

So, what is wrong with using `string::size_type`? Is this compiler specific? I am really confused because there are no error messages.

Comment: `Works perfectly fine` except when the string is empty in which case the behaviour of the program is potentially undefined, depending on implementation defined sizes of the integer types. `x.size()-1` is a very large unsigned number when size is 0.

Comment: To iterate in reverse, use reverse iterator. `for (auto i = x.rbegin(); i != r.end(); ++i) num.push_back(*i - '0');`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`string::size_type` is an unsigned type, which means it can never be negative. That means this condition:

```
i >= 0
```

will never be false. In fact, when `i` goes below `0`, it will wrap around, and become the *largest possible value* of `string::size_type`. Then when you index `x[i]`, you invoke undefined behaviour.

I would suggest writing the loop this way:

```
for(int i = static_cast<int>(x.size()) - 1; i >= 0; i--)
  // ...
```

Note the `static_cast` *before* the subtraction by 1 (otherwise you'll have issues with an empty string).

Unless you have *really* large strings, the length should be well within what an `int` can handle. If you do need a `string::size_type` index, you could do this loop as well:

```
auto i = x.size();
while (i-- > 0)
  // ...
```

Note this is robust to `unsigned` types. The comparison against `0` happens *before* the decrement of `i` (hence the post-decrement operator). So you nicely get the indices `size-1, size-2, ..., 1,0`. When `i` is `0`, the comparison will fail, and then the fact that `i` becomes a big positive number doesn't matter.

Comment: Don't worry about it, `unsigned` is confusing. Try to use just `int`s as far as possible.

Comment: Personally, I prefer the canonical "goes to" operator: `while (x --> 0)` Works with unsigned indices.

Comment: @eerorika I do too, personally, but I prefer not to *recommend* it :p It usually requires additional explanations.

Comment: @cigien In practice, I'll just move the space when writing for others :)

Comment: @eerorika that makes sense. Added that option to the answer.

Answer (score 3):

When you write loops that use an unsigned index and go backwards you have to change your idiom a bit:

```
for (std::string::size_type i = x.size(); i > 0; --i)
    num.push_back(x[i-1] - '0');
```

That way you don't have to deal with the possibility of subtracting 1 from 0.